# mongoose, trying to find one object by a value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to find one object by a value, and then adding that object to another objects property.

***Code***

q = {
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    category: QuestionCategory,
    question: String,
    name: String,
};

```
QuestionCategory.findOne().sort({ category: "ExampleCategory" }).exec((err, doc) => {
    if(err)
    {
        return err
    }
    q.category = doc;
})
```

error:

```
throw new TypeError('Invalid sort value: {' + field + ': ' + value + ' }');
    ^

TypeError: Invalid sort value: {category: ExampleCategory }
```

I've also tried without the .sort and write the filter inside findOne, but didn't work either

The Schema

```
const QuestionCategorySchema= new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    category: String,
    icon: String,
    order: Number
}, { collection: 'QuestionCategory' });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to query the documents with category field ExampleCategory you need to make a find query not a sort query 
and also there is no need of sorting the data when your are using findOne as it only gets one QuestionCategory
QuestionCategory.findOne({category:"ExampleCategory"}).exec(err, doc)=>{})

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer, when I do that I get this error instead.
CastError: Cast to Embedded failed for value "ExampleCategory" at path "category"

Comment: is there schema defined for this QuestionCategory collection?

Comment: if you are looking to fetch document with category value as "ExampleCategory" above query should work may be it is issue with your mongo connector , try using it in mongo shell

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can't use `sort()` like this `sort({ category: "ExampleCategory" })`, You need to sort like 
`.sort({ category: -1 })` OR `.sort({ category: 1 })`, Another thing we can't use `sort()` while performing top fetch a single record from database(Ex.`findOne()`). The  `sort()` basically used for sorting your data respectively your keys. By the way you can get your desired result by below query:

`QuestionCategory.find({}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1)`

Comment: I want to find the QuestionCategory that has the property category that matches the string that i throw in, will that query work for that?

Comment: Then the query will be:
`QuestionCategory.find({ "key": "value" }).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1)`